# Converting JS design pattern to CoffeScript occurred class error

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

On the Russian wikipedia i found the code of `Builder` design pattern and try to convert it in to the coffeescript. [Builder.js](https://gist.github.com/khaljava/8698840)

This is the gist of [Builder.coffee](https://gist.github.com/khaljava/8699139)

```
// Abstract Builder
function PizzaBuilder() {
    var pizza = new Pizza();
    this.getPizza = function() {
        return pizza;
    };
    this.createNewPizzaProduct = function() {
        pizza.clear();
    };
    this.buildDough = function(val) { };
    this.buildSauce = function(val) { };
    this.buildTopping = function(val) { };
}
// ConcreteBuilder
function HawaiianPizzaBuilder() {
    PizzaBuilder.call(this);
    var pizza = this.getPizza(); // imitation protected
    this.buildDough = function() { pizza.setDough("cross"); };
    this.buildSauce = function() { pizza.setSauce("mild"); };
    this.buildTopping = function() { pizza.setTopping("ham+pineapple"); };
}
```

I changed every function which is called by the constructor (new FuncName) to `class FuncName`, but an error occurred with `PizzaBuilder.call(this);` inside the constructor function.

```
PizzaBuilder = ->
    pizza = new Pizza()
    @getPizza = -> pizza
    @createNewPizzaProduct = -> pizza.clear()
    @buildDough = (val) ->
    @buildSauce = (val) ->
    @buildTopping = (val) ->

class HawaiianPizzaBuilder
    PizzaBuilder.call this
    pizza = @getPizza() # imitation protected
    buildDough: -> pizza.setDough "cross"
    buildSauce: -> pizza.setSauce "mild"
    buildTopping: -> pizza.setTopping "ham+pineapple"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript function `HawaiianPizzaBuilder` is a constructor of class. In Coffeescript you need to define it explicitly as `constructor` method, this way:

```
class HawaiianPizzaBuilder
    constructor: ->
       PizzaBuilder.call this
       pizza = @getPizza() # imitation protected
       @buildDough: -> pizza.setDough "cross"
       @buildSauce: -> pizza.setSauce "mild"
       @buildTopping: -> pizza.setTopping "ham+pineapple"
```

Also you forgot `this.` before `build...` function definitions.

However I would like to suggest another edition of same pattern example as coffeescript provides simpler class inheritance syntax, something like that:

```
class PizzaBuilder
    constructor: ->
        @pizza = new Pizza()
    buildDough: -> @
    buildSauce: -> @
    buildTopping: -> @

class HawaiianPizzaBuilder
    buildDough: -> 
        @pizze.setDough "cross"
        @
    #...override other methods


 builder = new HawaiianPizzaBuilder
 myPizza = builder.buildDough().buildSauce().pizza
```